# Escaping double quote is not working properly

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, xml-parsing, escaping

I am writing a parser in Java where I am writing a string in XML dom.

Here is my code

```
String val="\""+val+"\"";
String temp=StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(val);
node.setTextContent(temp);
```

Then i am using the LSSerializer

```
DOMImplementationLS domImplementation = (DOMImplementationLS)doc.getImplementation();
LSSerializer lsSerializer = domImplementation.createLSSerializer();
String tempString=lsSerializer.writeToString(doc);
```

And saving to the file.

Now my problem is a String "test" should come as ***& quot;test& quot;*** but it is coming as ***& amp;quot;test& amp;quot;***

It seems that & is escaped separately.Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string gets escaped twice.

1. `"test"` -> `&quot;test&quot;` (`"` escaped as `&quot;`)
2. `&quot;test&quot;` -> `&amp;quot;test&amp;quot;` (`&` escaped as `&amp;`)

I was tricked to believe that this line

```
node.setTextContent(temp);
```

already does the escaping, however it is not true...

[Node.setTextContent(String) API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#setTextContent%28java.lang.String%29):

> ...Similarly, on setting, **no parsing is performed either, the input string is taken as pure textual content**.

However, [LSSerializer](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html) does:

> Within the character data of a document (outside of markup), any characters that cannot be represented directly are replaced with character references. Occurrences of '<' and '&' are replaced by the predefined entities < and &. The other predefined entities (>, ', and ") might not be used, except where needed (e.g. using > in cases such as ']]>').

So either case, there is no need to do the escaping twice with `StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(val);`, you can leave out that line, resulting in:

```
String val="\""+val+"\"";
node.setTextContent(val);
```

Or even simpler:

```
node.setTextContent("\""+val+"\"");
```

Or a bit probably nicer to me (I don't like concatenating strings):

```
node.setText(String.format("\"%s\"", val));
```

**However,** I don't understand why you want `"` to be escaped, as that (in a text node) doesn't break the XML format....

Comment: I think you mean `node.setTextContent(val);` instead of `node.setTextContent(temp);`

Comment: @jlordo thanks, I didn't even notice there is a `temp` variable - I'd have left that out entirely myself...

Comment: I tried that earlier.If i remove this line StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(val); then it will not even escape the "" as a result it comes as "test"

Comment: @Crypt and why do you need `"` to be escaped? That doesn't break the XML formatting (unless it would be in an attribute, but this is not the case...)

Comment: @ppeterka.. ya i tried that and it's working.I thought " will break XML formatting.Thanks